# Guidance with f-string formatting documentation

Tags: python, f-string

I'm currently playing around with f-strings more and trying to figure out how to do things like

```
# Depth and decimal format
f"string text {var: #.#f}"

# Alignment format
f"string text {var: < #}"
```

I know that is how you would do a depth, decimal, and alignment format for a variable, but how would one format the string text and variable together? Such as

```
f"num = {dartsThrown: < 10d}"
```

```
print((f"num ={dartsThrown: < 10d}  Calculated PI = {computePI(dartsThrown):.6f}   "
       f"Difference = {differencePI:+0.6f}"))
```

how do you combine f-string formatting to both 'num = ' and {var}

Would I have to store it into a variable itself?

```
numVariable = 'num = ' + dartsThrown

f"{numVariable: < ##d}"
```

or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean combine the two together?

Comment: Yes, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the alignment specification before the width specification, per the documentation of the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> var=1.23
>>> f'{var:<8.1f}'
'1.2     '
>>>
```

Comment: I just updated my question to be more clear, but thanks for the help.